# Stop timer in jQuery and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to stop timer when popup is active.

I have two popups where it works. But it doesn't work with first one which is automatic when the page is on.

````
// Calling function - this is in popup.html
var popUp1 = false;
var popUp2 = false;

// Calling function with instruction by click
function togglePopup(){
  popUp1 = document.getElementById("popup-1").classList.toggle("active");
  timeToggle()
}

// Calling function with description by click
function myFunction(){
  popUp2 = document.getElementById("desc").classList.toggle("activeD");
  timeToggle()
}

// function for pausing game when there is popUp
function timeToggle(){
  if (!popUp1 && !popUp2){
    Init();
  }else{
    clearInterval(moveItIntervalID); //stopping time and random images
    clearInterval(timeIntervalID);
  }
}

//here is funcion with automatic popup
    $( document ).ready(function() { 
        $('#descS').bPopup();
        timeToggle()

(function(c){c.fn.bPopup=function(A,E){function L(){a.contentContainer=c(a.contentContainer||b);switch(a.content){case "iframe":var d=c('<iframe class="b-iframe" '+a.iframeAttr+"></iframe>");d.appendTo(a.contentContainer);t=b.outerHeight(!0);u=b.outerWidth(!0);B();d.attr("src",a.loadUrl);l(a.loadCallback);break;case "image":B();c("<img />").load(function(){l(a.loadCallback);F(c(this))}).attr("src",a.loadUrl).hide().appendTo(a.contentContainer);break;default:B(),c('<div class="b-ajax-wrapper"></div>').load(a.loadUrl,a.loadData,function(d,b,e){l(a.loadCallback,b);F(c(this))}).hide().appendTo(a.contentContainer)}}function B(){a.modal&&c('<div class="b-modal '+e+'"></div>').css({backgroundColor:a.modalColor,position:"fixed",top:0,right:0,bottom:0,left:0,opacity:0,zIndex:a.zIndex+v}).appendTo(a.appendTo).fadeTo(a.speed,a.opacity);C();b.data("bPopup",a).data("id",e).css({left:"slideIn"==a.transition||"slideBack"==a.transition?"slideBack"==a.transition?f.scrollLeft()+w:-1*(x+u):m(!(!a.follow[0]&&n||g)),position:a.positionStyle||"absolute",top:"slideDown"==a.transition||"slideUp"==a.transition?"slideUp"==a.transition?f.scrollTop()+y:z+-1*t:p(!(!a.follow[1]&&q||g)),"z-index":a.zIndex+v+1}).each(function(){a.appending&&c(this).appendTo(a.appendTo)});G(!0)}function r(){a.modal&&c(".b-modal."+b.data("id")).fadeTo(a.speed,0,function(){c(this).remove()});a.scrollBar||c("html").css("overflow","auto");c(".b-modal."+e).unbind("click");f.unbind("keydown."+e);k.unbind("."+e).data("bPopup",0<k.data("bPopup")-1?k.data("bPopup")-1:null);b.undelegate(".bClose, ."+a.closeClass,"click."+e,r).data("bPopup",null);clearTimeout(H);G();return!1}function I(d){y=k.height();w=k.width();h=D();if(h.x||h.y)clearTimeout(J),J=setTimeout(function(){C();d=d||a.followSpeed;var e={};h.x&&(e.left=a.follow[0]?m(!0):"auto");h.y&&(e.top=a.follow[1]?p(!0):"auto");b.dequeue().each(function(){g?c(this).css({left:x,top:z}):c(this).animate(e,d,a.followEasing)})},50)}function F(d){var c=d.width(),e=d.height(),f={};a.contentContainer.css({height:e,width:c});e>=b.height()&&(f.height=b.height());c>=b.width()&&(f.width=b.width());t=b.outerHeight(!0);u=b.outerWidth(!0);C();a.contentContainer.css({height:"auto",width:"auto"});f.left=m(!(!a.follow[0]&&n||g));f.top=p(!(!a.follow[1]&&q||g));b.animate(f,250,function(){d.show();h=D()})}function M(){k.data("bPopup",v);b.delegate(".bClose, ."+a.closeClass,"click."+e,r);a.modalClose&&c(".b-modal."+e).css("cursor","pointer").bind("click",r);N||!a.follow[0]&&!a.follow[1]||k.bind("scroll."+e,function(){if(h.x||h.y){var d={};h.x&&(d.left=a.follow[0]?m(!g):"auto");h.y&&(d.top=a.follow[1]?p(!g):"auto");b.dequeue().animate(d,a.followSpeed,a.followEasing)}}).bind("resize."+e,function(){I()});a.escClose&&f.bind("keydown."+e,function(a){27==a.which&&r()})}function G(d){function c(e){b.css({display:"block",opacity:1}).animate(e,a.speed,a.easing,function(){K(d)})}switch(d?a.transition:a.transitionClose||a.transition){case "slideIn":c({left:d?m(!(!a.follow[0]&&n||g)):f.scrollLeft()-(u||b.outerWidth(!0))-200});break;case "slideBack":c({left:d?m(!(!a.follow[0]&&n||g)):f.scrollLeft()+w+200});break;case "slideDown":c({top:d?p(!(!a.follow[1]&&q||g)):f.scrollTop()-(t||b.outerHeight(!0))-200});break;case "slideUp":c({top:d?p(!(!a.follow[1]&&q||g)):f.scrollTop()+y+200});break;default:b.stop().fadeTo(a.speed,d?1:0,function(){K(d)})}}function K(d){d?(M(),l(E),a.autoClose&&(H=setTimeout(r,a.autoClose))):(b.hide(),l(a.onClose),a.loadUrl&&(a.contentContainer.empty(),b.css({height:"auto",width:"auto"})))}function m(a){return a?x+f.scrollLeft():x}function p(a){return a?z+f.scrollTop():z}function l(a,e){c.isFunction(a)&&a.call(b,e)}function C(){z=q?a.position[1]:Math.max(0,(y-b.outerHeight(!0))/2-a.amsl);x=n?a.position[0]:(w-b.outerWidth(!0))/2;h=D()}function D(){return{x:w>b.outerWidth(!0),y:y>b.outerHeight(!0)}}c.isFunction(A)&&(E=A,A=null);var a=c.extend({},c.fn.bPopup.defaults,A);a.scrollBar||c("html").css("overflow","hidden");var b=this,f=c(document),k=c(window),y=k.height(),w=k.width(),N=/OS 6(_\d)+/i.test(navigator.userAgent),v=0,e,h,q,n,g,z,x,t,u,J,H;b.close=function(){r()};b.reposition=function(a){I(a)};return b.each(function(){c(this).data("bPopup")||(l(a.onOpen),v=(k.data("bPopup")||0)+1,e="__b-popup"+v+"__",q="auto"!==a.position[1],n="auto"!==a.position[0],g="fixed"===a.positionStyle,t=b.outerHeight(!0),u=b.outerWidth(!0),a.loadUrl?L():B())})};c.fn.bPopup.defaults={amsl:50,appending:!0,appendTo:"body",autoClose:!1,closeClass:"b-close",content:"ajax",contentContainer:!1,easing:"swing",escClose:!0,follow:[!0,!0],followEasing:"swing",followSpeed:500,iframeAttr:'scrolling="no" frameborder="0"',loadCallback:!1,loadData:!1,loadUrl:!1,modal:!0,modalClose:!0,modalColor:"#000",onClose:!1,onOpen:!1,opacity:.7,position:["auto","auto"],positionStyle:"absolute",scrollBar:!0,speed:250,transition:"fadeIn",transitionClose:!1,zIndex:9997}})(jQuery);

function Init(){
//set interval of moving image in case the user will not click it
    moveItIntervalID = setInterval(moveIt, intervalTimeout);
    timeIntervalID = setInterval(countDown, 1000);```
````

Comment: Well, it doesn't work because you're not even calling the function. On docready open the popup using one of your own functions or call `timeToggle()`.

Comment: When I'm calling funcion like this:
```JavaScript
$( document ).ready(function() { 
        $('#descS').bPopup();
        timeToggle()
    });
```
something strange happens - time goes faster O.o

Comment: Maybe you're setting the timer twice. What does `Init()` do?

Comment: part of it:

```JavaScript
function Init(){
//set interval of moving image in case the user will not click it
    moveItIntervalID = setInterval(moveIt, intervalTimeout);
    timeIntervalID = setInterval(countDown, 1000);```

Comment: note that in modern HTML the script element supports the `defer` attribute (even IE11 supports it) which tells the browser to load the script "whenever" but only _run_ your script _after_ the DOM is done, so load jquery and your own script with `defer`, and you no longer need `$( document ).ready(function() {` at all. jQuery's getting very old on the web these days: regular JS's kind of caught up and surpassed it in many areas.